# How to solve graphdoc markdown error in Django

Tags: django, graphene-django

I am trying to output the graphql docs in Django using graphdoc package and the following source code:

```
return HttpResponse(
            graphdoc.to_doc(FileUploadGraphQLView().schema),
            content_type='text/html'
        )
```

however, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A type error related to a `__proxy__` often indicates you're referencing a lazy object of some type. Try explicitly passing the `.schema` through `str` or another appropriate function to force the lazy object to be evaluated.

Lazy objects are created [by the `lazy` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2.7/django/utils/functional.py#L85).